# Max Output Voltage preamplifier

Tags: audio

I'm looking for a preamplifier to get 1-2 Volt as Maximum Output Voltage from a microphone with jack or RCA.

It should get a line-in signal and then modulate in FM. I've found one potential option, though I'm not 100% sure if it works for what I want, because to modulate in FM I need to know exactly the Maximum Output Voltage the microphone line-level can get: [Behringer MA400](https://www.thomann.de/es/behringer_ma_400.htm?glp=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiA0b_QBRCeARIsAFntQ9qKqxsLdbmJCPvAnOreQln6HexcD-QzMCDxQJEZ5sBQUKRem5o69B4aAo74EALw_wcB).

[image]

I'd like to be able to regulate the output. I'm gonna put this output into an FM modulator circuit that I made with VCO.

Do you know a product or something like I'm looking for?